# Network status not showing

Tags: windows-10

I ended some tasks and services because of high RAM usage. Now I cannot see network status. I tried clicking troubleshooter but nothing shows up. Which services and processes should I restart?

Comment: Just restart the computer ...

Comment: I have already done it.It is still not working